# Bit wise operations in C

Tags: c, bit-manipulation

I'm working on a C programming assignment, I need to simulate the operation of a 3 bit decoder. My compiler is complaining, this Wikipedia article gives a list of C operators, but my code still seems not to be working.

Wikipedia: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operators_in_C_and_C%2B%2B#Bitwise_operators

Compiler error:

```
logic.c: In function ‘three_bit_decoder’:
logic.c:33: warning: statement with no effect
logic.c:33: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘~’ token
logic.c:34: warning: statement with no effect
logic.c:34: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘b0’
logic.c:35: warning: statement with no effect
logic.c:35: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘~’ token
logic.c:36: warning: statement with no effect
logic.c:36: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘b0’
logic.c:38: warning: statement with no effect
logic.c:38: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘b0’
logic.c:39: warning: statement with no effect
logic.c:39: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘b0’
logic.c:40: warning: statement with no effect
logic.c:40: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘~’ token
logic.c:41: warning: statement with no effect
logic.c:41: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘b0’
logic.c:43: warning: return makes integer from pointer without a cast
logic.c:43: warning: function returns address of local variable
make: *** [logic.o] Error 1
```

Code:

```
int three_bit_decoder(BIT b0, BIT b1, BIT b2) {
    /* Returns an 8 bit number, by 2^3
     * 
     */
        int myIntDecoder[8]; 

        myIntDecoder[0] ~b0 + ~b1 + ~b2;
        myIntDecoder[1] b0 + ~b1 + ~b2;
        myIntDecoder[2] ~b0 + b1 + ~b2;
        myIntDecoder[3] b0 + b1 + ~b2;

        myIntDecoder[4] b0 + ~b1 + ~b2;
        myIntDecoder[5] b0 + ~b1 + b2;
        myIntDecoder[6] ~b0 + b1 + b2;
        myIntDecoder[7] b0 + b1 + b2;

        return myIntDecoder;
}
```

Comment: Looks like you're missing some assignment operators.

Comment: Nothing like a dumbass attack. I caught that just after I posted.

Comment: `return 1<<(((b2<<1)+b1<<1)+b0);`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If those are assignment statements you're missing equal signs.

```
myIntDecoder[0] = ~b0 + ~b1 + ~b2;
myIntDecoder[1] = b0 + ~b1 + ~b2;
myIntDecoder[2] = ~b0 + b1 + ~b2;
myIntDecoder[3] = b0 + b1 + ~b2;

myIntDecoder[4] = b0 + ~b1 + ~b2;
myIntDecoder[5] = b0 + ~b1 + b2;
myIntDecoder[6] = ~b0 + b1 + b2;
myIntDecoder[7] = b0 + b1 + b2;
```

The next problem you'll encounter is that `int myIntDecoder[8]` declares an array of 8 ints, which is not the same as an 8-bit int. A `char` is 8 bits wide on (almost) all platforms; or you can be more explicit and use one of the standard typedefs:

```
#include <stdint.h>

uint8_t myIntDecoder;
```

So as not to leave you hanging, I should mention that assigning to individual bits in a variable is not as simple as `byte[5] = 1`. Doing it requires some clever use of shifting and other bitwise operations.

Comment: ... Nothing like a dumbass attack, I caught that seconds after posting. How do I setup an 8bit int?

Comment: So do I cast the int array to the by or just add it?

Comment: @Snow_Mac Get rid of the array. You don't need anything using square brackets.

Comment: `uint8_t` is the proper way with C99. It's in `<stdint.h>` IIRC.

Comment: so whats the byte[5] thing then?

Answer (score 1):

The bitwise operators are not your problem, you have syntax errors in your code. Think about how to do assignment of variables and the solution should come to you.

Answer (score 1):

Presumably you're after something like:

```
   myIntDecoder[0] = ~b0 + ~b1 + ~b2;
   // and likewise for the other 7 lines
```

That won't help with trying to return `myIntDecoder` though. For that, you'd probably want to move the array outside the function and (for one example) pass its address into the function.

Answer (score -3):

you are missing the equals operator.

```
myIntDecoder[7] = b0 + b1 + b2;
```

Also the not operator in c is `!` not `~`

Comment: `!` is logical not, `~` is bitwise not. `! != ~`.

Comment: ... According to Wikipedia, the ! is a logical operator, the ~ is a bitwise operator. Same idea different context.

Comment: You guys are right, I really should be sleep now instead of answering in StackOverflow without thinking first.